# Executing multiple Tasks asynchronously inside an asynchronous Task

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, task

I have the following WCF endpoint:

```
    public string AddPlace(Place placeBounds, ...)
    {

        FetchAllSocialPlatforms(placeBounds);

        Place newPlace = PlaceDB.AddPlace(placeBounds, ...);

        return newPlace;
    }
```

...where `FetchAllSocialPlatforms()` is:

```
    private Task FetchAllSocialPlatforms(Place bounds)
    {
        try
        {
            Task<int> taskTwitter = FetchTwitter(bounds, user);
            Task<int> taskInstagram = FetchInstagram(bounds, user);
            Task<int> taskFlickr = FetchFlickr(bounds, user);
            Task<int> taskYouTube = FetchYouTube(bounds, user);

            Task.WhenAll(taskTwitter, taskInstagram, taskFlickr, taskYouTube);

            SendNotificationOnComplete(...); // Azure Service Bus / SignalR message back to app

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(...);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

My intention is to return `newPlace` to the caller (in this case it's the JavaScript web application) while `FetchAllSocialPlatforms()` is working in the background on the server side. Once all fetching from all platforms are completed, a notification is sent.

So far, my code runs synchronously instead of asynchronously and the `newPlace` isn't returned until all fetching is completed.

I realize I don't have my head completely wrapped around the Task and await operations and I'd love to know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

**Edit #1:**

I was asked to show more code implementation, so here it is:

```
    private async Task<int> FetchTwitter(Place bounds)
    {
        int count = 0;
        try
        {
            count = Fetch(bounds, PlatformType.Twitter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(...);
        }

        SendNotificationOnComplete(count, ...); // Azure Service Bus / SignalR message back to app

        return count;
    }
```

`FetchInstagram`, `FetchFlickr`, and `FetchYouTube` all follow the same logic.

Comment: So `FetchAllSocialPlatforms` starts a bunch of tasks to create some information, but you never actually do anything with that information.  You start the tasks, continue on with the program without waiting for them, and never do anything when they finish.  And the only way that method would be synchronous is if each of the `Fetch` methods, which you haven't shown the implementation of, are all synchronous.

Comment: In addition, it's usually a mistake to do "background processing" on a web/api server. Is your WCF service hosted in ASP.NET?

Comment: @Servy I've updated the post with more info.

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, it's hosted on an ASP.NET Azure instance.

Comment: Your `FetchTwitter` isn't actually asynchronous.  It's entirely synchronous.  Your code will generate a warning telling you exactly that, because you have an `async` method with no `await` in it.  Fundamentally your `Fetch` method looks to be synchronous, not asynchronous.  You need to have an asynchronous method of doing the IO that you want to perform to actually get any benefits out of writing asynchronous code.

Comment: @Servy But even if `Fetch` was not an asynchronous method, it is being called inside an asynchronous Task, so it should be running in its own process asynchronously along other Tasks. Correct?

Comment: @AlbertEltawil No, none of that is true.  A method being `async` only means that you're allowed to use the `await` keyword.  It doesn't result in the method being run in another thread and it doesn't make it asynchronous.  Your method is in no way whatsoever different from a regular synchronous method that calls `Task.FromResult` on it's result (well, technically it also wraps any exceptions in a task too, but you already catch them and prevent them from escaping the method).

Comment: @Servy I see. Do you think you can show me a re-write of my code that makes it work asynchronously. It will certainly help a lot.

Comment: @AlbertEltawil No, I cannot, because you don't have an inherently asynchronous IO method available to you, nor is it clear at all what this code should be doing, how it should work, etc.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for your help. I added my modified code below and it appears to work.

Comment: @AlbertEltawil: What's the implementation of `Fetch`?

Answer (score 0):

I modified my code and it appears to work as desired.

**AddPlace(...)**

```
    public string AddPlace(Place placeBounds, ...)
    {

        FetchAllSocialPlatforms(placeBounds);

        Place newPlace = PlaceDB.AddPlace(placeBounds, ...);

        return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(newPlace);
    }
```

**FetchAllSocialPlatforms(...)**

```
    private async Task FetchAllSocialPlatforms(Place bounds)
    {
        try
        {
            Task taskTwitter = FetchTwitter(bounds);
            Task taskInstagram = FetchInstagram(bounds);
            Task taskFlickr = FetchFlickr(bounds);
            Task taskYouTube = FetchYouTube(bounds);

            var complete = Task.WhenAll(taskTwitter, taskInstagram, taskFlickr, taskYouTube);
            await complete.ContinueWith((c) =>
            {
                SendNotificationOnComplete(...); // Azure Service Bus / SignalR message back to app
            });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error(...);
        }

    }
```

**FetchTwitter(...)**

```
    private async Task FetchTwitter(Place bounds)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            int count = 0;
            try
            {
                count = Fetch(bounds, PlatformType.Twitter);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(...);
            }

            SendNotificationOnComplete(count, ...); // Azure Service Bus / SignalR message back to app

        });
        await t;
    }
```

Again, `FetchInstagram`, `FetchFlickr`, and `FetchYouTube` all follow similar code logic.

Comment: Where does `Fetch` come from, if it is a 3rd party library there may be an asynchronous version of the call. If it is your function show us it and we may be able to show you how to make it asynchronous. Doing `Task.Run` on a IIS server is rarely a good idea unless your server is very underutilized. It *may* make it complete faster but you will be decreasing your total capacity. Using "true async" calls instead of spawning threads gives you faster code while maintaining (or increasing) capacity.